# How to identify a parent div for an image that exists within a table cell?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables, each of which is contained within different divs, similar to what we see here:

```
<div id="prices">
    <table>
        <tr class='hidden-row'>
            <td>
                <img class='expand-collapse-icon' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="performance">
    <table>
        <tr class='hidden-row'>
            <td>
                <img class='.expand-collapse-icon' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have some jQuery code that selects hides/shows some of the rows when you click the image. The problem is that it's showing rows from *both* tables, rather than the table the image exists in.

That's because of the way I'm selecting the rows:

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').click(function() {
    $(".hidden-row").toggle(); // it's finding all hidden rows in both tables.
});
```

I'm having trouble selecting only the rows associated with the current table I've clicked. I tried identifying the specific div I'm in with this:

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').parent('td').parent('tr').parent('table').parent('div')
```

but this doesn't work. It just returns a jQuery object with a length of 0, so it's obviously not finding the parent div. Is there a better way of me selecting only the rows that exist within the correct table?

Comment: Use `$(this)` instead of `these` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').closest('div');
```

Closest searches the dom-tree upwards for the next occurence of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is this:

```
var element = $('.expand-collapse-icon').parents('div:eq(0)');
```

Comment: This won't work. `parent()` selects only immediate parent of the element, which is actually `<td/>`. You could use `parents('div')` here, it is somewhat unsafe, since it would select all `div` ancestors. So `closest('div')`, as @Boo suggested, is the best bet.

Comment: I use .parents('div:eq(0)') - read this: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#index

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').parent('td').parent('tr').parent('table').parent('div')
```

use this

```
$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').parent('table').parent('div')
```

**or**

```
$(this).parent('td').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
```

Comment: What's the point of using such a construction, when you can use `closest()`?

Comment: @unclenorton: Agreed!! but what if there are more than one `<div>` in the parent `<td>`...that would then get control of the one that is closest that is the one inside the `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').click(function() {
  var div = $(this).closest("div");
  if (div.id == 'prices') {
    // do X
  } else {
    // do Y
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work either:

```
$('.expand-collapse-icon').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('div').hide(); // it's finding clicked img's parent div and hiding it.
});
```